# How to avoid reload data when tabs change?

Tags: android

How can I avoid a recyclerview to reload when the tabs change?
For example, I have a TabLayout with three Tabs, my ViewPager is:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Tab1Fragment();
                case 1:
                    return new Tab2Fragment();
                case 2:
                    return new Tab3Fragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "tab1";
                case 1:
                    return "tab2";
                case 2:
                    return "tab3";
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

In the first one, I have a recyclerview, when I change the tabs and back to the first one, the list is reloaded. 
There is a way do avoid this reload? Just keep the data loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android keeps only one fragment on either side of the current fragment in a `ViewPager` by default. So when you come back to your first tab from the third one, it will recreate the first tab which is what is happening in your case. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) is the documentation.

You need to keep all the Fragments in memory with 
`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(<(number of fragments in view pager) - 1>)` which is 2 in your case.

Of course, as the docs suggest, this number should be kept low especially if its a complex layout.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```